# Can I clone drupal site on the same server?

Tags: drupal

We would like to upgrade our D6 site to D7 version. It's a kinda big site but we tried to clone the site on the same server using the same files and database. So the set up is :

Production - 
database: db
folder: www/drupal

Clone:
database:db2
folder: www/drupal2

anything from production has been copied. We just updated the settings.php, The idea is to make all upgrades to clone site then just switch by just renaming the folder and updating settings.php again.

However, we can only have the homepage displayed/ Other pages are blank.

Any prompt help from you will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Answer**

Actually something similar happened to me recently after cloning a site. The .htaccess file was ignored by GIT, so I could see the frontpage but not the rest of the site!

Of course, after copying the .htaccess file, everything went back to normal!

---

This is not really a Drupal question actually...

If you want to duplicate your site, just create a copy of the site onto a subdomain...

In your case it wouldn't help much though. You'd be better off looking at the Migrate module which should allow you to create a fresh Drupal 7 install on another domain.

You will then import your D6 content into your D7 install, without having to worry about breaking anything from your original D6 site.

Admittedly the Migrate module may not be the easiest to learn but for a heavy site, it may be your best solution out there for a clean Drupal upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on a sub donain or the main, but you can always create as many copies as you want of your site. You have to follow these steps:
1) Take back up of your current site db.
2) Install Drupal in another directory and import the db you have taken back up of

There is another way to clone your site using Drush/Aegir. This will require access to SSH and drush/Aegir must be installed on your server.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it depended on the subdomain :) They seem to have a problem accessing their cloned site on the same server!