# Clone a Drupal site in the same multi-site installation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-multi-domain

I want to make a clone of one of the sites on my Drupal multi-site installation so I can try out some changes without impacting the live site. Unlike the question [Can I clone drupal site on the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20313996/3333) I don't want to create a new drupal installation, I want it within the same multi-site installation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you just have to add a new *site/xxx* folder containing the right **settings.php**.

If you want to use the same code, on the same server, it should be enough :)

Comment: Except I looked through the database dump on the original site and it has hard coded URLs, so if I just clone the database it will use the same files.